# Can I use Springs JpaRepository to retrieve Logback LoggingEvent records that have been appended using DBAppender

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, logback, spring-logback

The spring-boot application I'm working on uses Logback's classic `DBAppender` to add log entries to a (Postgres) database.

I would like to access these records, preferably using a `JpaRepository` for `LoggingEvent`.

I've tried creating my own `LoggingEvent` entity matching the schema of Logback's own `LoggingEvent` class, and making that a Jpa `@Entity`. However, using the `logging_event` table for my `LoggingEvent` class seems to in some way inhibit Logback from using the table itself. Some log entries are appended, but others (e.g all logs from the spring `RestController`s) are not.

What is the most spring-congruent way of accessing these entries without interfering with Logback's database appender?

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <property resource="config.properties"/>
    <property resource="application.properties"/>
    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs"/>

    <!--APPEND LOG TO DATABASE-->
    <appender name="Database" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename</url>
            <user>postgres</user>
            <password>postgres</password>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Database"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No I don't get any exceptions. I have a console appender (not included in the logback.xml for brevity) which still functions fine after the db appender stops working.

Comment: can you turn on debug or trace logging for logback itself? maybe you see some messages. I don't see a reason why your approach should not work.